# Can an MVC2 or MVC3 html.routelink contain &laquo and &raquo?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routelink

What's the syntax for displaying this? My program will always render « literally in the pagination helper I am creating, and since the switch to MVC3 there seems to be no way to even hack it with Eval( string.FromCharCode )

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use the corresponding UTF-8 character and the HTML helper will take care of the encoding it:

```
@Html.RouteLink("«", new { action = "navigate", page = 1 })
@Html.RouteLink("»", new { action = "navigate", page = 3 })
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are using UTF-8 as your character-set then showing the « directly (without encoding it) is perfectly valid XHTML.